# What Type of Options should be on the Game Settings Menu?

Tags: android, game-design, menu

I have seen a post about the main menu options here:
[UI: Main Menu options for mobile games. What options should be listed? What do users want to see?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17047/ui-main-menu-options-for-mobile-games-what-options-should-be-listed-what-do-u)

But I want to know what kind of options should/need to be available on the settings screen.

I am making a rather simple 2D game for Android, but really I haven't found many aspects that warrant an options button or a check box besides turning the sound and music on/off.  I was thinking graphics settings but then again, how many apps really need graphics settings besides immersive 3D ones?

Comment: Add the options you need and none more.  If all you have are volume, fine.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, this is really kind of opinion-based.  But the simpler the better seems like a standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your options/config as simple as possible and include only what all players would likely use, such as volume.

That said, it may be a good idea to add an **Advanced** or **Extra** button that takes the user to an extra config screen where you could add many different things that the average user may never want/need (such as resetting progress, tweaks for different device sizes, etc). Because mobile devices (and their users) are so varied it may benefit you to have options that allow them to customize their experience.

In the end, it will largely depend on your game and it's intended audience. If it is a really simple game, and volume is your only option, it might be best to just include it on the main screen and skip the options screen - or even better, just have a mute button available at all times (main menu, pause menu, etc) since most mobile devices can handle volume manually.